# Find the location of a device

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to find the location of a close by device for example if I have 2 devices A and B, can device A find out the **exact** location of device B if it's at an arm's length or a few feet away? Through bluetooth or something like that?

Comment: you should run a service in your application and synchronize the locations of the devices

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006701/is-it-possible-to-find-other-nearby-phones

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. They would have to communcate via any network connection and query each others location (aquired by GPS or any other source).

It could be possible though to traingulate using many devices with known locations. Depending on your use-case this could be an option. The more devices with known locations you can place, the more exact you will be able to traingulate through Bluetooth visibility and signal strength (Physical Address Randomization might make this difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Exact distance finding is not possible, But using Bluetooth **signal strength** you can find nearest devices